# How can I tell which number my contact used to call me?

Tags: contacts, call-history, caller-id

I've got a contact with several different (mobile) numbers. When they call me, I see their name, but not the specific number they're currently using. Also when looking at the call history after the call, I only see their name, and not which number was used.

1. Is there a setting I can change to make Android show me the specific number used when receiving a call?
2. Is there a setting I can change to make Android show me the specific number used when browsing call history?
3. In the absence of such a setting as asked for in no. 2 above, is there some other way when browsing call history to tell what number was used for a call?

Comment: This might be a setting in your caller app. I've just checked my call history, and for each incoming/outgoing call I see e.g. "John Doe (mobile)" or "John Doe (business)". If your caller app doesn't have a setting for that, take a look at your contacts app and whether you can assign such a dedicated category to each number (I have it in mine, that's where "mobile" or "business" come from). Maybe you should even start with the latter. If all numbers from a contact have the same category, that would explain why you don't see the difference.

Comment: Thanks, @Izzy. Yes, my contact has two (private) mobile numbers, and I labelled both as 'mobile'. I could replace one with a custom label, but I wish Android could just show me the actual number :-/

Comment: There're always things left to wish for – but if you have a work-around, the real issue is at least "solvable". // Be welcome to [answer your own question](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) when it works out – or if you prefer, let me know if I shall make that above comment an answer.

Comment: Thanks, @Izzy. You're welcome to write an answer, but please note: a workaround is _not_ an answer :) A real answer should address points 1, 2, and 3 of the question, answering them in the negative if what I ask for can't be done (ideally with some reference, so that whoever reads it knows it really can't be done, not just that we couldn't find the way). Of course, adding the workaround would be a bonus improving the answer :)

Comment: OK Tom: then the comment will have to do – making it less easy for other affected users to see the available work-around.

Comment: @Izzy, again: you can write it as an answer – but please mention that it is a workaround, and that there is no way to do what I asked for. (Sorry if I'm being too pedantic, it's just that I've had very bad experiences on SE with "answers" which don't really answer the questions they're posted on... Yet another option would be to publish a different question, for which this workaround actually is the answer, and post it as an answer there :) )

Comment: I got it, Tom, and I understand. Maybe you just upvote the comment for now to make it "stick out" (no points for me, but might help those looking for the same issue).